# javascript input validation is not working on the first try

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is a script on a HTML input form. My problem is that when for the first time I enter something in the input box I get the wrong result, but when I focus on the box again (click in the input box) and then deselect the input box I get the right answer! why this is happening??? what is the solution?

```
<input type="email" id="iemail" name="email" class="form-control"></input>
<script>
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    var userinput;
    $("#iemail").focus(function(){
        userinput = $("#iemail").val();
    });
    $("#iemail").blur(function(){
        if(pattern.test(userinput)){
            alert("VALID");
        }else{
            alert("not a valid e-mail address");
        }
    });
</script>
```

could anybody please help me. I will really appreciate it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're assigning a value to `userInput` on the `focus` event of the field, which for the first time `focus` is triggered, when the field is blank, will mean `userInput` is set to a blank value.

You could move the assignment of `userInput` to the `blur` event instead.

```
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i;
$("#iemail").blur(function(){
    var userinput = $("#iemail").val();

    if(pattern.test(userinput)){
        alert("VALID");
    }else{
        alert("not a valid e-mail address");
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to edit your post. I thought i was editing mine to make mine more clear. I rolled back the edit.

Comment: I did, I rolled it back to your original revision. Unfortunately, it will still show my name there. Have an upvote though because your answer is a correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this :

```
 $("#iemail").focus(function(){
        userinput = $("#iemail").val();
    });
```

change blur to :

```
$("#iemail").blur(function(){
        userinput = $("#iemail").val();
        if(pattern.test(userinput)){
            alert("VALID");
        }else{
            alert("not a valid e-mail address");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you are globally storing the value of `#iemail` on focus. The **first** time it focuses, it globally stores an empty string since you haven't type anything yet. When you blur, it checks that empty global string. The second time you focus, it now has a value in the text box and stores that.

No need to do these things separately.

```
$("#iemail").blur(function(){
    var userinput = $("#iemail").val();
    if(pattern.test(userinput)){
        alert("VALID");
    }else{
        alert("not a valid e-mail address");
    }
});
```